# WiFi communication to embedded display

Tags: embedded, wifi, avr

I'm trying to create an embedded outdoor display of bus arrival times at my university. I'd like the device to utilize my school's secured WiFi network to show arrival time updates determined from a server script I have running.

I was hoping to get some advice on the high-level operation of this thing -- would it be better for the display board to poll a hosted database via the WiFi network or should I have a script try to communicate with the board directly over 802.11? (Push or Pull?)

I was planning to use a Wifly or WIZnet ethernet board in combination with a wireless access hub. Mostly inspired by this project: http://www.circuitcellar.com/Wiznet/winners/001166.html  Would anyone recommend something else over one of the WIZnet boards? I saw SPI/UART options and thought these boards could work with an AVR platform.

And out of curiosity -- if you were to 'cold start' this device (ie, request a bus arrival time by pushing the display's on button) you might expect it to take 10-20 seconds to get assigned an IP and successfully connect to the database, does that sound right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go pull.  In fact, I'd have outdoor display make http or https requests of the server.  That way the server could tell it how long to show a given set of data before polling for a new one using standard http page expiration.

I think pull would make it easier to have multiple displays, and to test your server as well.  I've also got a gut feeling that this would make your display more secure.  Someone would have to hack your server to hijack your display.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very cool looking Arduino-targetted product called the [WiShield](http://www.asynclabs.com/store?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=17&category_id=6&vmcchk=1). Seems super easy to use and he provides some source code. It uses SPI for host communication. If you're not interested in going the Arduino route, I'm sure the source code wouldn't be too hard to port to something like avr-gcc. Check it out, might save you some time and headaches for $55. Worth checking out anyway.

Comment: Yeah, thanks!  I checked that out.  It sadly doesn't (yet) support DHCP and that's a must on my school's network.  I ended up buying the WiFly board from SparkFun. Communication is through USART. It's working well so far!

Comment: Cool I'll have to check that out!